# Why isn't WKAlertAction Showing?

Tags: ios9, xcode7, watchos-2

I want to show alert view like `UIAlertview` using watchkit extension (watchOS2), 
`WKAlertAction` is not showing in willActivate.

But it shows after some trigger like tapping button and so on.

Is there any mistake?

```
- (void)willActivate {

   [super willActivate];


   WKAlertAction *alertButtonAction =

   [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"confirm"
                            style:WKAlertActionStyleDefault
                          handler:^{}];

  [self presentAlertControllerWithTitle:@"title"
                              message:@"message"
                       preferredStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert
                              actions:@[alertButtonAction]];
}
```

Environment : Xcode 7 GM seed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

It seems that WatchOS app **cannot show alert right after app start**!

I moved the code for creating and presenting alert into *dispatch_after* (as an experiment) and delayed execution for 3 seconds.

Then everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, in the "second page" controller of a paged navigation. Then I noticed that sometimes `willActivate` is triggered even if the page in the segue is not going to show (the same thing happens with `awakeWithContext`, but this is documented by Apple).

So I moved the presentation of the Alert in `didActivate` and now it works. I also experimented Maciej's solution while leaving the alert in `willActivate`: it shows up (I'm curious to understand why) but of course, in my case, on the wrong page controller (i.e. the first and only page that really activated).

Comment: I can't find `didActivate` in the WatchKit. 